# Which Technology Trend In Development Is Promising To Follow In 2011?

Tags: java, python, apache-flex

Dear guys 
I am going switch to java , i want to know which development technology is promising for future development of apps , is my choose reliable

My top keys are multi platform , wider community , support of latest technologies like smart devices , ...

Also i am not satisfied with adobe ( flex / air ) i think i totally waste my time due to performance and many issues like server side processing and ...

My Other choose is python 
Any word from u could help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Java is suitable for your requirement. Still in Java,  you have to choose framework like struts, spring... very carefully. But there are lot of forums and blogs are availables. They will guide you.

Comment: yes , i did ask but out here many fan guys make war instead of help , as long as i know spring MVC is more promising !?

Comment: @Synxmax, thats true, but there are some sites like stackoverflow, martin folwer(blogger), springsource.org, Help is always there in Java technology. java site have lot of documents, www.theserverside.com.

Answer (score 1):

1. For UI, [SpringMVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) is gaining
   more and more supports from the
   community. Struts is a bit old.
2. For the Core Framework,  still
   [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org/documentation). Or you may
   want to consider [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html)as alternative.
3. For the DAO, still [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/).
4. For the mobile, [Android](http://developer.android.com/index.html) and
   [Sencha Touch(EXT-js)](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) are
   promising.
5. [Google Apps Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) is also interesting. Supports Java + Python.